# can't change scaling on second monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

Monitor 1 is 4k

Monitor 2 is HD

Monitor 1's Scale is 200%, and I would like to change the Scale of Monitor 2 to 100%. But when I select "100%" for Monitor 2, it also changes Monitor 1's Scale to 100%.

Example: setting the display in M2 to 100%
[image: Setting M2 display to 100% scale]

After clicking apply, both displays change to 100% scale and I automatically see this screen:
[image: M1 and M2 display are set to 100% scale]

How can I set just M2 to 100% scale, and keep M1 at 200%?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I can only select different scale ratios for internal and external display if I activate Fractional Scaling. Even if I want to use 100% and 200%, only.

The following is working, here:

Fraktional Scaling [X], internal display: 3840x2400 200%, external display 1280x1024 100%.

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.1 with GNOME on Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Yoga Gen 7, D-Link DUB-M810 8-In-1 USB-C Hub with HDMI out, Benq FP73E display